# Can the same thread ID be reused within the same process?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm storing information per thread in a map (map's key is the thread ID).

However, I'm wondering if this is really a good idea. I see that every thread has a different ID, but does that really mean "every thread" or just "every live thread". I mean, within the same process, can a new thread use the same ID as an old thread that ended?

I experience that on Android, for two different threads, strangely `syscall(__NR_gettid)` are different while `boost::this_thread::get_id()` are identical. Is it a "bug", or is it just likely to occur.

Comment: The identities of your threads should not be so important. Don't conflate the thread itself with the work that the thread is supposed to do. If you need to identify different _tasks_ that your program's threads perform, then create your own IDs for those tasks.

Comment: @besmirched: Got it. Actually, I ended up with statics `__thread` variables which actually makes the things work just right by having the variable be defined separately for each thread (my original map was static).

Comment: Being able to distinguish a long running thread from a new thread with a reused thread ID can be important when debugging multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `pthread` (which both `std::thread` and `boost::thread` use) says,

> Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only within a process.  A thread ID may be reused after a terminated thread has been joined, or a detached thread has terminated.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html

So, yes, a new thread **may** reuse an ID from a dead thread inside the same process.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux [`boost::this_thread::get_id`](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp#L728) returns the result of [`pthread_self()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html):

> Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only within a process. A thread ID may be reused after a terminated thread has been joined, or a detached thread has terminated.
>
> The thread ID returned by `pthread_self()` is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to `gettid(2)`.